# bzr get last commit message using bash

Tags: bash, scripting, bazaar

I am using bash to try and get the last commit message of the most recent revision on a tree. In the documentation the closest thing I found was:

```
bzr log -l 1 --line
```

Which outputs:

```
45: Firstname Lastname 2013-11-20 some message here
```

I want to use bash regex to extract the message however the fact that the name field can be:

```
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Initial Lastname
Firstname Lastname <email>
Initials
Username <email>
Username
```

It makes it a lot harder. I don't need you to build me a regex I would just like to know:

1. If bazaar has some command that shows the message (cant find in http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.5/en/user-reference/index.html)
2. Should I use regex and use the date as the anchor to parse out message?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this SO Q&A titled: [bzr logs: Get just the commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712770/bzr-logs-get-just-the-commit-messages). You can use `bzr log --short` or write your own custom log formatter via a plugin to bazzar.

You can see more about the log formats using this command:

```
$ bzr help log-formats
```

In looking through the effort to make your own formatter through a plugin, I'd be inclined to just use one of the stock ones and run the output through either an awk or Perl filter.